# Symfony 5 / Request Response : Get data with Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, request

when I try to get data in ajax, the returned object is empty

I send the id of the data I want to get in js :

```
    function selectMessage(id) {
         
        $.ajax({
                url: '{{ path('back_translation_update') }}',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {id: id}
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
         
    }
     
    $('.updateMessage').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation()
        selectMessage($(this).data('id'))
    })
```

in the controller I look for the data to return :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/update", name="back_translation_update", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function getById(Request $request): Response
    {
        if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
             
            $id = $request->get('id');
//            dd($id);
             
            $message = $this->translationService->getTranslationById($id);
             
//            return new JsonResponse(['data' => $message]);
 
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setContent(json_encode([
                'data' => $message,
            ]));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
        }
                 
    }
```

I use a service because with the repository I get an error: *getById () must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response*

with :

```
$repositoryMessage = $this->em->getRepository(TranslationMessage::class); 
$message = $repositoryMessage->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
```

so the service will look in the database:

```
public function getTranslationById($translation_id)
{
    $query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from(TranslationMessage::class,'message')
        ->select('message')
        ->where('message.id = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $translation_id);
     
    $message = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
//    dd($message);
    return $message;
}
```

all the dd() give the expected values:

- into getById(): the id of the row sought
- into getTranslationById(): the sought object

but in the XHR, data contains an empty object: uh:

same with a new JsonResponse, commented here

what did I miss? help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Aurowire to get messageRepository object and use `$this->json()` to return JsonResponse

```
/**
* @Route("/update", name="back_translation_update", methods="GET|POST")
*/
public function getById(Request $request, TranslationMessageRepository $messageRepository): JsonResponse
{        
    $id = $request->query->get('id');
    $message = $messageRepository->find($id);

    if(!$message) { return new NotFoundHttpException(); }

    return $this->json([
         'success' => true,
         'data' => $message
    ]);
                 
}
```

Define success function instead of done function

```
function selectMessage(id) {
        $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('back_translation_update') }}",
                method: 'GET',
                data: { id: id }
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }

        })
         
}
```

Comment: Great thanx I get it! I just have to adapt url path to get it from js file because there is locale parameter, so thanx one again